# How to get the number of servers your bot has joined and display it on the status of the bot

Tags: python, url-rewriting, discord.py

I want some code that switches the status from Playing <help to Playing {number of servers} servers every 30 mins using `task.loop()`

Please help me

Comment: Hey there Slimey! Do you have any code that you have tried? Stackoverflow is, more often than not, not a code-writing service. Please include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you have tried, as well as the traceback that was given to you. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You can create variable `status_state` and use it to know what status you need to set up:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import tasks

status_state = True

@tasks.loop(minutes=30)
async def change_status():
    global status_state
    new_status = "<help" if status_state else f"{len(bot.guilds)} servers"
    await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Game(new_status))
    status_state = not status_state

change_status.start()
```

Comment: error: "status_state" is not defined

Comment: @TheSmileyDeveloper_TV I edited my answer. See it again. please